# Storing numeric values in Lucene 6.5.0

Tags: java, lucene

I need to Store the Numeric field in the Lucene docs, but Lucene 6.5.1 the signature of the NumericField is like

> NumericDocValuesField(String name, long value)

In older lucene versions the method is like,

> NumericField(String, Field.Store, boolean)

. 
Can someone guide me how to store the numeric values in the document using lucene6.5.1.

Regards,
Raghavan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NumericDocValuesField is used for scoring/sorting only:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/NumericDocValuesField.html

If you like to store any kind of values (including numeric) you have to use a StoredField:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html

Depending on what you need you have to add multiple fields for multiple purposes. If you have a numeric value as long and you like to do range queries and sort you would do something like this:

```
// for range queries
new LongPoint(field, value);
// for storing the value
new StoredField(field, value);
// for sorting / scoring
new NumericDocValuesField(field, value);
```

Comment: How can it setting a integer for doc values?  also using "NumericDocValuesField"?  I can't found IntDocValuesField  on lucene 7.x

Comment: why do you need integer there? not able to work with long?

Comment: I found org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparator.IntComparator,  so i think maybe we can store exact integer doc values

Comment: for me this sounds like a general field comparator for index numbers (which are positive integers). is there a real "problem" if you work with a long value instead of int? as for use of the standard sorting api this should be the way to go, IMAO.

Answer (score 1):

Use special type oriented numeric fields:

```
IntField intField = new IntField("int_value", 100, Field.Store.YES);
LongField longField = new LongField("long_value", 100L, Field.Store.
YES);
FloatField floatField = new FloatField("float_value", 100.0F, Field.
Store.YES);
DoubleField doubleField = new DoubleField("double_value", 100.0D, 
Field.Store.YES);
```

You can store their values and sort them if you need. All of those field are indexable.

Comment: This field types are deprecated legacy Fields. Like LegacyIntField. I would recommend not using this.